# jquery - a flat json string to a grouped nested jquery string

Tags: jquery, json, nested

I have a flat json file

```
[{"Category":"WO","cfg_item":"WO10018","ID":43,"SortOrder":43},
{"Category":"Milestone Status","cfg_item":"Open","ID":23,"SortOrder":1},
{"Category":"Milestone Status","cfg_item":"Complete","ID":24,"SortOrder":2},
{"Category":"Milestone Status","cfg_item":"Ready","ID":218,"SortOrder":0},
{"Category":"Milestone Health","cfg_item":"Green","ID":14752,"SortOrder":0},
{"Category":"Milestone Health","cfg_item":"Amber","ID":14753,"SortOrder":1}]
```

and I would like to group and nest the file like this using jquery.

```
[
   {
      "Category":"Milestone Health",
      "data":[
         {
            "ID":14752,
            "cfg_item":"Green",
            "SortOrder":0
         },
         {
            "ID":14753,
            "cfg_item":"Amber",
            "SortOrder":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Category":"Milestone Status",
      "data":[
         {
            "ID":218,
            "cfg_item":"Ready",
            "SortOrder":0
         },
         {
            "ID":23,
            "cfg_item":"Open",
            "SortOrder":1
         },
         {
            "ID":24,
            "cfg_item":"Complete",
            "SortOrder":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

please find a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2bitcoder/5dsygone/

so far I have nested but not grouped the data - I'm unsure how to do the grouping.

```
var newjson = jsondata.map(function (item) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[item.Category] = { cfg_item: item.cfg_item, ID: item.ID, SortOrder: item.SortOrder};
        return obj;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), here's a simple way:

```
_.map(_.groupBy(collection, "Category"), function(value, key) {
  return {
    "Category": key,
    "data": value
  }
});
```

[Demo with ommiting the category in the "data" property](http://jsfiddle.net/5dsygone/5/)

Comment: I've selected this as the correct answer because I already have underscore.js in my project - so this was the easiest answer for me.  - Thank you !

Comment: I'm glad to help! And indeed, @charlietfl's answer also solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Can do it by building a temporary object whose keys are the categories, then loop over that object to build the final array

```
var tmp = {}, newjson = [];

$.each(jsondata, function(_, item){
    if(!tmp[item.Category] ){
        tmp[item.Category] = [];
    }        
    tmp[item.Category].push( item);  
    delete item.Category;  
});

$.each( tmp, function( category, dataArr){        
    newjson.push({Category: category, data: dataArr})
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5dsygone/6/)**</kbd>